# How to differentiate component in angular 6

Tags: angular5, angular6, angular2-services

I am trying to create a global component but that is working same like in all places..i want to use with different label values and in many palaces like aglobal component.I am learning angular 6 so facing trouble now. How do it to resolve?

service:

```
  addComp(Names,c){
  let item = {name: Names, componentid: c};
  if (this.item.find((test) => test.name === Names) === undefined) {
  this.item.push(item);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Input` decorator to declare values in your `BreadcrumbDemoComponent` that you want to be different, and pass those values as properties in the selector tag.

Example:

**app-component.html**

```
<breadcrumb-demo [label]="'Value 1'"></breadcrumb-demo>
<breadcrumb-demo [label]="'Value 2'"></breadcrumb-demo>
```

**breadcrumb-demo.component.ts**

```
...
export class BreadcrumbDemoComponent {
@Input() label;
...
}
```

**breadcrumb-demo.component.html**

```
...
<h1>{{ label }}</h1>
...
```

Comment: Not working..lable means like Home/Satrting0/ect...Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: @SEERANSV I'm sorry, I didn't understand. What do you want the labels to be again?

Comment: @SEERANSV One thing, keep in mind that the `"value 1"` and `"value 2"` in the selector tag are variable names. If you want to pass strings, use `"'value 1'"` and `"'value 2'"` (that's a double quote followed by a single quote)

Comment: @SEERANSV I've edited the stackblitz. Is that close to what you want? If not, please try describing it a little more precisely.

Comment: How can i use that global component in multiple times? in my stackblitz when i click on label like Home both component working same time how to avoid this?

Comment: @Akash..I think u understood

Comment: I am waiting for you reply